# Unique Constraint in fportfolio in R

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

I am wondering if it is possible to set a constraint on a portfolio based on a unique value assigned to each asset.

Simple example -- I have 3 assets and they have different investment expenses.

Asset 1 - 0.10%

Asset 2 - 0.20%

Asset 3 - 0.50%

Is there a way to implement a constraint that would keep the total portfolio investment expense less than 0.25%?

Asset 1 * 0.10% * Weight + Asset 2 * 0.20% * Weight + Asset 3 * 0.50% * Weight <= 0.25%

I am open to other packages in R but hoping this is possible in the fportfolio.